# How to search a playlist in brightcove

Tags: brightcove

All -

I have implemented a simple html page and added brightcove js file and flash code to it. The code displays playlist for the user and a player. Does brightcove give us the ability to search from the playlist?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Playlist read api methods.
http://docs.brightcove.com/en/media/reference.html#Playlist_Read

they return the members of the playlist. you need additional code to search within its members.

Answer (score 0):

If playlist is too large, response may fail. Brightcove provides pagenation and total page number for each json element. So call first page and get total page number. Iterate all pages, call each page and get a playlist. And concatenate each playlist into an array which is the playlist.

```
var dataPageSize = 10;
var brightcoveAPiUrl ="https://api.brightcove.com/services/library";
var callBrightcove= function(data){ 
  return  $.ajax({
  url: brightcoveAPiUrl,
  dataType:'jsonp',
  data:data
  )}
};
    function getPlaylist(pageNumber) {
        return callBrightcove({
                    "command": "find_all_playlists",
                    "playlist_fields": "id,name,filterTags",
                    "page_number": pageNumber,
                    "page_size": dataPageSize,
                    "get_item_count": "true",
                    "token": brightcoveReadToken
                }
        );
    }
function getAllPlaylist() {
        var startPageNumber = 0;
        getPlaylist(startPageNumber).done(function (data) {
            var dataArr = [data];
            var playlistArr = [], requests = [], i;
            var requestCount = parseInt(data.total_count / dataPageSize);

            // Deferred Requests Array
            for (i = 0; i < requestCount; i++) {
                requests.push(getPlaylist(i + 1).done(function (data) {
                    dataArr = dataArr.concat(data);
                }))
            }
}
```